# Mail merge with Word and not-an-Excel document

Tags: microsoft-word, csv, mail-merge

I know it's possible to do a mail merge with Word + Excel spreadsheet. But how is it possible to do a Word mail merge with addresses in a TXT or CSV file?

Example of Word document:

```
From :
ABC
Address
Zipcode City

                               to:

                                            MailMergeLine1
                                            MailMergeLine2
                                            MailMergeLine3
                                            MailMergeLine4

Dear Sir, Dear Madam, 

...
```

Example of CSV file:

```
MailMergeLine1;MailMergeLine2;MailMergeLine3;MailMergeLine4
CDE;2 ABC Street ;1234;London
FGH;12 XYZ Street ;6789;Paris
```

Comment: Find an ODBC driver that understands CSV, or do it the easy way e.g. use Excel.

Comment: @Hannu No no, I want to use a CSV or TXT file for simplicity and avoid the use of Excel, so if I have to set up an ODBC driver, it will finally be more complex than just doing a simple XLS file ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Select the Mail Merge tool

[image]

2. Choose `Text files (.txt, .csv, etc.)`

[image]

3. Then insert some fields (and choose the `Preview` option as well on the right of the ribbon)

[image]